# Web Components Listeners Unbind at Destruction

Tags: javascript, listener, web-component

I am building a Web Component for an input that binds listeners for the `focus` and `blur` events in JavaScript.

I am extending from an `HTMLElement` and I use the `constructor` to initialize my components and the events binding.

My question is: do I need to unbind these listeners in the case the `DOMNodeRemoved` event is triggered for instance? Is it a good habit to have or is it useless and the JavaScript engine can clean old reference to the DOM node associated to my Web Component and clean it along with its listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the event listeners are inside the element (attached to the custom element or any element inside it) you don't need to do anything, they will get cleared when the element is gone. However you should clear the ones attached to the global scope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you happen to have some resources I can link to like an official MDN documentation? Even if that is not specific to Web Components but DOM elements created in JavaScript in general.

Comment: This article should explain some things about "Garbage Collection": https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/